# How to add Display attribute to model

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Example.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Models are in a separate project, because I want to use them in several applications that work with the same database. The 'Display' attribute name can be different in different applications. I can not inherit classes in applications and set attributes in metadata because can not cast IEnumerable<Product> to IEnumerable<DerivedProduct>. What do I do?

Comment: If you need the `Display` attribute, you have a UI need. UI models are commonly referred to VIewModels. You should return `Product` and let each client implement their own `ProductViewModel` according to their needs

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : It sounds reasonable, but in my case, the data model and the view model will be the same. As a result, I get overhead by converting the same models into each other and filling navigation properties and collections manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It's not possible add attributes from other class automatically. You need write your own metadata provider inherited from `IDisplayMetadataProvider` (if you want edit property display settings) or/and `IValidationMetadataProvider` (if you want edit property validation messages).

```
   public class MyMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider, IValidationMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
        }

        public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

In ASP .NET Core MVC you need add instance of your provider to provider list in Startup.cs.

```
services.AddMvc(c=>c.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new MyMetadataProvider()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to define validation attributes in separate class, that is then linked with original class through [`MetadataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465(v=pandp.50).aspx) attribute.

Here is how to do it for `Product` class:

1.Declare `ProductMetadata` class with the same properties that original class has:

```
internal class ProductMetadata
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "SomeName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

2.If possible, remove any attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace from your your original class `Product`. This step is optional and is desirable for avoiding unused attributes. If you can't modify original class or those attributes are required for some reasons, leave them as is.

3.Now you have to mark original class with `MetadataType` attribute specifying metadata class type. If you could add the attribute to existing class `Product` then it's simple:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public class Product
{
    // ...
}
```

If however the model class is in separate project as you describe, you could assign that attribute dynamically. Put this code somewhere close to application startup:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Product), new MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ProductMetadata)));
```

That's it. These steps should do the trick.

Comment: This does not work. The ModelMetadataType attribute (for ASP .NET Core) is added to the main class attributes, but the attributes of the metadata class are not processed.